# What's the fastest way to remove an object from an array that has a specific property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I remove:

```
var arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8}];
```

the object in the array with `b` set to 2?

Comment: to me, it's not clear what your asking for... please clarify! Do you want to remove an element from the array arr if b==2 ?

Comment: You want to take a look at [MDN: Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `[...]The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = arr.filter(function( a ) {
    return a.b !== 2;
});
```

This will only work for IE9+

Comment: `2 !== '2'`  is `true`

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way to do that would be a for loop, correct me if I'm wrong...

```
var arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8}];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].b==2) { arr.splice(i,1); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to jsperf the **fastest way to delete an array element** is to use `delete array[index]`. Source: http://jsperf.com/object-delete-vs-array-splice-vs-array-delete

A solution could be this: http://jsfiddle.net/no20bv5o/3/

But because of the overhead in the for loop and the second array it is slower as the before mentioned `arr.filter()` as shown by this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/filter-array-by-element-attribute

Comment: In your fiddle the `length` remains `4`  and just the _index_ `0` is removed. While it _removes_ the given element from the array it leaves a gap.

Comment: You are right, I adjusted the code and compared it to the filter method above, which is then faster: http://jsperf.com/filter-array-by-element-attribute

Comment: Using `max -= 1` and also `i-=i` does not make any sense. The `max -= 1` is even wrong, because it will fail to remove one element if you have two element with `b==2` and one of them is the last element in the array. The your `fiddle` (without the  `max -= 1` ) _correctly delete_  all elements (but leaving gaps).

Comment: Thanks I think there are better solutions here and i will remove the answer.

Comment: It depends on the use-case, but `delete` on an array should normally not be used, because it behaves different then people would expect.